# What did Frank Sinatra think of the Sinatra Doctrine?

Tags: soviet-union, cold-war

Frank Sinatra died seven years after the introduction of the [Sinatra Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinatra_Doctrine) in the Soviet Union. I'm wondering if he ever commented on it, especially since the Soviets named it after him.

Comment: According to his daughter, Frank hated "My Way", so he might not have been too pleased with the association.